# PHP unique identy field in url

Tags: php

I have dilemma. I need unique string in my database table to show it in url (I don't show id in url).

I want generate in php unique string check it is unique in table if not generate new.

What do you think in terms of performance for a string with a length of 8 characters, and with a large number of rows (about 100,000 rows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a unique id in php using [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php).

When generating a new ID, check the DB to see if it exists. If it does, create a new one. **Assuming you set up an index on that column in the database**, these checks will not be very expensive.

In pseudo(-ish) code :

```
while (true) {
  $id = uniqid();

  if (!id_exists_in_db($id)) // we have a unique id
    break;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for code but I think mainly about performance you answer me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of generating a unique key besides the id, you can also create a function that hashes or encodes the id to a string. For instance, you can convert the integer to an 8 character hexidecimal representation. You can make it a little more complex if you like, but still, it's fairly easy to write a function that uses a fixed formula to convert a number to 8 letters and vice versa. That way, you don't need to store this extra data, and you don't have to worry about the value being unique.

```
<?php

function translate($key, $back)
{
  $key = str_pad($key, 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  $a = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0');
  $b = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j');
  if ($back) {$c = $b; $b = $a; $a = $c;}
  return str_replace($a, $b, $key);
}

function encode_id($int)
{
  return translate($int, false);
}

function decode_id($key)
{
  return (int)translate($key, true);
}

$key = encode_id(40000);
$int = decode_id($key);
echo $key;
echo '<br>';
echo $int;
```

Comment: Good idea but in my case is not that simple.

Comment: Why not, if I may ask?

Comment: I prefer not to give your idea :)